# Getting Error : is not a delta table in Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

The Question is:

Complete the `writeToBronze` function to perform the following tasks:

1. Write the stream from `gamingEventDF` -- the stream defined above --
   to a bronze Delta table in path defined by `outputPathBronze`.
2. Convert the (nested) input column `client_event_time` to a date format and
   rename the column to `eventDate`
3. Filter out records with a null value in the `eventDate` column
4. Make sure you provide a checkpoint directory that is unique to this stream

Code :

```py
def writeToBronze(sourceDataframe, bronzePath, streamName):
  (sourceDataframe    
     .withColumn("eventDate", 
        to_date(col("eventParams.client_event_time"), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
     .filter(col("eventDate").isNotNull())     
     .writeStream
     .format("delta")
     .option("checkpointLocation", f"{bronzePath}_checkpoint")
     .queryName(streamName)
     .outputMode("append") 
     .start(outputPathBronze)
  )
    
writeToBronze(gamingEventDF, outputPathBronze, "bronze_stream")
```

Below is the Error I get:
[image]

Comment: Can you `%fs ls` this directory?

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this too but have just figured it out
In the provided template for this capstone cell they have included the line:
.start(outputPathBronze)
This is referring to a parameter that is outside of the function, not the path passed in as an argument. The reality check passes a different path in that variable.
If you change this line to use the variable bronzePath you should be able to get past that step (now I have to get my count to match their expected count...)